# SAML support in 2013 SP1

Tags: 2013, ldap

I was reading some things about the `SAML` support in 2013 SP1, but I was wondering if it's possible to link Tridion directly to a SAML server to get a token?

Because as I now understand it, SAML support is only enabled for the communcation between GUI (content explorer / `XPM`) and the Core Webservices, and initial authentication still goes over `LDAP`? (so Tridion server both generates and validates the tokens)

Anybody already tried to link Tridion directly to an external `SAML` server or is this not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point, Tridion provides SSO option via HTTP Headers from an authenticated proxy in front of Tridion GUI. SAML assertions/IDP for Tridion GUI is not supported yet, AFAIK.

Comment: Just got this confirmed by Tridion support as well. SAML is currently not supported as a default SSO, playing with the HTTP header information could be an option.